# Write to windows disk from WSL (Windows subsystem for Linux)

Tags: linux, windows

I'm in need to share files between Linux (using WSL) and Windows, so that I can edit in Windows and compile in Linux. According to recomendations from Microsoft I should then keep my shared files under the drive in /mnt/ (/mnt/c/ in my case). Problem I have is that trying to write to that drive in Linux yields a Operation not permitted, I need to do sudo for all writes. How can I change this so that I have write possiblitites from my Linux?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In WSL `/mnt/c` is a mount of the root of drive C (`C:\`) in Windows. You should not store files in the root of Windows' system drive - this is normally write protected for normal users which I guess is what you experience.

The correct thing to do is moving in deeper to your Windows user folders, fx `/mnt/c/Users/YOU/Documents`. Here you are permitted to write files from WSL.

Comment: I have stored all the files under my windows user folder, not under the root. Was unclear in the question about this